# Error Message Pushing to Github after Commit: fatal: protocol error: bad line length 819273.70 MiB/s

Tags: git, github

I have been trying to upload some files from a cloned git repository on my desktop (I am the creator and owner of the repository) to my git repository online, simply to use as a file backup and to share with my boss. At first, I got this message whenever I tried to push my files:

```
 Enumerating objects: 44, done.
 Counting objects: 100% (44/44), done.
 Delta compression using up to 16 threads
 Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
 error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 41
 fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
 Writing objects: 100% (41/41), 10.63 GiB | 211.10 MiB/s, done.
 Total 41 (delta 6), reused 2 (delta 0)
 fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
 Everything up-to-date
```

I found this solution, which seemed to fix the problem: [Link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-779171796.html), by entering this code (the number is the size of the largest file that I'm pushing):

```
  git config --global http.postBuffer 7526196184
```

Now however, I am getting this message instead:

```
 Enumerating objects: 44, done.
 Counting objects: 100% (44/44), done.
 Delta compression using up to 16 threads
 Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
 fatal: protocol error: bad line length 819275.81 MiB/s  
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/willmonty14/Brain-Immune-Cell-Project.git'
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi. Check limits. How big is local repo? How much can GitHub take? 10 GB looks way too much for me. If I have a file bigger then 50 MB, I put it into .gitignore. Git is for small text files, normally.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I don't actually know how to do that, can you suggest a command? And what is .gitignore? Thanks for your time.

Comment: `cd <FOLDER> && du . -h | sort -h`. `.gitignore` prevent files from being added, committed and pushed. You can create this file in main folder (where `.git` folder sits). Big files have to be copied another way. Are you using Windows?

Comment: Nope, I'm on Mac. How can I copy the big files? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: AirDrop? Nextcloud? USB stick?